# How to stabilize facial landmarks from Dlib or Mediapipe?

Tags: python, computer-vision, dlib, mediapipe

I'm using dlib and mediapipe to get facial landmarks arround a face image. My question is about the jittering. In Mediapipe, the researchers advise us to use temporal filter like the one euro filter to reduce the jittering. But I noticed that, in two consecutives frames that are similar, without mouvement, the facial landmarks is not stable. So I observe the detected bounding box arround the face, and it is not stable too. Is it a common solution to stabilized the detected bounding box before the estimation of the facial landmarks?

Comment: You can average out the predictions for a few frames